# "Custom Cursor cannot be converted to String" Exception is thrown while converting the cursor to string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to change the cursor of my control on certain conditions. I have created my own custom cursor and assigned it to the Cursor.Current property. Everything working fine up-to this.

When I check whether the current control cursor and the new cursor is same or not based on their names by converting cursor using ToString() method, I get:

> Custom Cursor cannot be converted to String

There is no problem in converting the System's default cursor and it raise only when converting custom cursor. Any one please tell me why this exception raised only on custom cursor?

this is the place where i got the error...
 ****if (m_cursorAction.ToString() != newCursor.ToString())**
        m_cursorAction = newCursor;**

Here is my cursor implementation code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(140, 25);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
using (Font f = new Font("SEGOE UI", 10))
    g.DrawString("Node 30", f, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
Cursor.Current = MyCursor.CreateCursor(bitmap, 140, 25);

**if (m_cursorAction.ToString() != newCursor.ToString())**
    m_cursorAction = newCursor;

public class MyCursor
{
    #region Class members
    private static IntPtr ptr;
    public struct IconInfo
    {
        public bool bIcon;
        public int xHotspot;
        public int yHotspot;
        public IntPtr hbmMask;
        public IntPtr hbmColor;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Class Public Methods
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, ref IconInfo pIconInfo);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateIconIndirect([System.Runtime.InteropServices.In]ref IconInfo icon);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32")]
    extern internal static bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a custom cursor with the given bitmap
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bmp">Bitmap for the cursor.</param>
    /// <param name="xHotSpot">x hot spot to the cursor.</param>
    /// <param name="yHotSpot">y hot spot to the cursor.</param>
    public static System.Windows.Forms.Cursor CreateCursor(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, int xHotSpot, int yHotSpot)
    {
        IntPtr bmpPtr= bmp.GetHicon();
        IconInfo icon = new IconInfo();
        GetIconInfo(bmpPtr, ref icon);
        icon.xHotspot = xHotSpot;
        icon.yHotspot = yHotSpot;
        icon.bIcon = false;
        DestroyIcon(bmpPtr);
        DeleteObject(bmpPtr);
        ptr = CreateIconIndirect(ref icon);
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(ptr);            
        //delete the GDI objects and icon
        DeleteObject(icon.hbmColor);
        DeleteObject(icon.hbmMask);
        DestroyIcon(icon.hbmColor);
        DestroyIcon(icon.hbmMask);
        return cursor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Destroy the custom cursor      
    /// </summary>
    public static void Destroy()
    {
        DestroyIcon(ptr);
        DeleteObject(ptr);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How don't you implement your own ToString method?

Comment: Where is `newCursor` defined?

Comment: could you highlight where the exception occurred?

Comment: @GrantWinney that looks like the OP assigned a `Cursor` to a string variable.

Comment: @CodeCamper: The variable is type `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor`, the `ToString()` method is defined by that class.

Comment: This error is very strange. Your `Cursor` has nothing special, it just inherits the `Object` by default (as like any other classes) and `ToString()` should work, without overriding, it should return a string of `Type name`. Your exception looks like the problem is occurred by a wrong `assignment` with casting exception not by a call to `ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Because it delegates to `CursorConverter.ConvertTo`, which is designed to throw that exception only for custom cursors.

Just don't use string comparison to test whether cursors are equal.  Instead, use the [`Cursor.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9shwts45.aspx) method which is designed for comparing cursors.

Comment: I wonder why calling `ToString()` on an object should be thrown with an exception, that's very strange. Because `ToString()` is called to display any kind of object as a string conveniently. That doesn't matter and there is meaningless to make it work that way.

Comment: @KingKing: I do have to agree with that.  The behavior described in the question seems to violate the `Object.ToString()` as everyone understands it.  But there's also no requirement that the return value be useful for comparison.  And I can't see anywhere in the actual code that would cause an exception.

Comment: @KingKing: Nevermind, was following the wrong branch.  The exception throwing code is there indeed.

Comment: of course, using `Equals` is better than anything, but the point is sometimes `ToString()` can help us show basic info conveniently, I wonder why the `ToString()` applied on a custom cursor shouldn't be `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor` or something like that... As you said, this is surely by design and we can hardly change the way it works (even overriding is not possible because `Cursor` is sealed)

Answer (score 0):

One way, for custom Cursors, if you know what you're looking for, is to check the Handle:

```
// 65569 = Hand Pointer:
int handle = 65569;

if (handle == System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Handle.ToInt32())
    MessageBox.Show("Hand Pointer Cursor");
```